Elstrodt: Maß- und Integrationstheorie, exercise II.1.12
I am trying to solve exercise II.1.12 from the book on Measure Theory by Elstrodt, but I don't really know how to start.

Definition
Let $\mathfrak{H}$ be a semi-ring over the set $X$. A map $\mu: \mathfrak{H} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is called a content if it has the following properties:
(i) $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$
(ii) $\mu \geq 0$
(iii) For every finite sequence of disjoint sets $A_1,...,A_n \in \mathfrak{H}$ with $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \in \mathfrak{H}$:
$\mu \left(\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \right) = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \mu(A_j).$


Exercise II.1.12
Let $\mu: \mathfrak{H} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\nu: \mathfrak{K} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be contents on the semi-rings $\mathfrak{H}, \mathfrak{K}$ over $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Let $\mathfrak{H} \star\mathfrak{K} := \{A \times B: A \in \mathfrak{H}, B \in \mathfrak{K}\}$ and $\rho: \mathfrak{H} \star\mathfrak{K} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be defined as $\rho(A \times B) := \mu(A) \cdot \nu(B) \quad (A \in \mathfrak{H}, B \in \mathfrak{K})$. Here the product on the right-hand side is defined as $a \cdot \infty := \infty$ for $0 \leq a \leq \infty$ and $0 \dot \infty := 0$. Show that $\rho$ is a content on $\mathfrak{H} \star\mathfrak{K}$ (Hint: Exercise I.5.5).


Exercise I.5.5
Let $\mathfrak{H}$ be a semi-ring over $X$ and $A_1,...,A_n \in \mathfrak{H}$. Show that: There exist disjoint sets $B_1,...,B_p \in \mathfrak{H}$ such that every $A_k \quad (k=1,...,n)$ can be written as a union of some $B_\nu$.

Now, it is easy to see that $\rho(\emptyset) = \mu(\emptyset) \cdot \nu(\emptyset) = 0$ and that $\rho \geq 0$ since $\mu \geq 0$ and $\nu \geq 0$, but I am struggling a lot with proving that $\rho$ is additive.
We have to show that for $A_1 \times B_1,...,A_n \times B_n \in \mathfrak{H} \star \mathfrak{K}$ with $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j \in \mathfrak{H} \star \mathfrak{K}$, we have
$$\rho \left(\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j \right) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \rho(A_j \times B_j).$$
Since $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j \in \mathfrak{H} \star \mathfrak{K}$, we know that $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j = A \times B$ for some $A \in \mathfrak{H}$ and $B \in \mathfrak{K}$. However, I don't see how I can relate the sets $A_j \times B_j$ to $A \times B$ to use the fact that $\mu,\nu$ are contents. I am pretty sure that's what the hint is for, but I simply don't know how to start since clearly $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j \neq \bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times \bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} B_j$. Also $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \rho(A_j \times B_j) = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \mu(A_j) \cdot \nu(B_j)$, but we somehow need to separate $\mu$ and $\nu$ to be able to apply the properties of $\mu$ and $\nu$.
I would appreciate if anyone could help me getting started.
Thanks a lot!

Apply the Lemma to the collections ${A_j}$ and ${B_j}$ to write each of those as a disjoint union of some ${C_k}$ and ${D_l}$. Then your sum becomes a sum over measures of sets of the form $C_k \times D_l$, and it should be possible to use this to show what you want to show. ... Essentially, my comment boils down to "Use the hint"

@Smiley1000 Thanks for your comment. I have added part of the proof  based on this idea, but I am still struggling with the last few steps. Could you please have a look? Thanks!

I think it should now be possible to show that actually the set is equal to $\bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^m C_m \times \bigcup\limits_{l = 1}^n D_l$. Then we have $\rho \left( \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^m C_m \times \bigcup\limits_{l = 1}^n D_l \right) = \mu \left( \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^m C_m \right) \cdot \nu \left( \bigcup\limits_{l = 1}^n D_l \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^m \mu(C_m) \cdot \sum\limits_{l = 1}^n \nu(D_l)$.

@Smiley1000 But $\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{m} C_k \times \bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{n} D_l$ allows for any combination of the $C_k$ and the $D_l$ whereas a union over a cartesian product only admits specific combinations.

I think that because of $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j \in \mathfrak{H} \star \mathfrak{K}$, we can write $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j = E \times F$ for $E \in \mathfrak{H}$ and $F \in \mathfrak{K}$, and I believe that we should then in fact have $E = \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^m C_k$ and $F = \bigcup\limits_{l = 1}^n D_l$.

@Smiley1000 Maybe, but that requires a proof. How would you show that? We don't really know anything specific about the sets $E$ and $F$.

Proof: We know that $\bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^n A_j \times B_j \in \mathfrak{H} \times \mathfrak{K}$. Hence we can write $\bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^n A_j \times B_j = E \times F$ for $E \in \mathfrak{H}$ and $F \in \mathfrak{K}$. ...

... Now we have $\bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^n A_j \times B_j = \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^n \left( \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^{m_j} C_{j_k} \right) \times \left( \bigcup\limits_{l = 1}^{n_j} D_{j_l} \right) \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^n \left( \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^m C_k \right) \times \left( \bigcup\limits_{l = 1}^n D_l \right) = \left( \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^m C_k \right) \times \left( \bigcup\limits_{l = 1}^n D_l \right)$. ...

... On the other hand, take any $1 \leq k \leq m$ and $1 \leq l \leq n$. They occur somewhere, meaning that there are $j_1, j_2$ with $C_k \subseteq A_{j_1} \subseteq E$ and $D_l \subseteq B_{j_2} \subseteq F$. Since $k$ and $l$ were arbitrary, we now have $\left( \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^m C_k \right) \times \left( \bigcup\limits_{l = 1}^n D_l \right) \subseteq E \times F = \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^n A_j \times B_j$. ...

... This shows that $\bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^n A_j \times B_j = \left( \bigcup_{k = 1}^m C_k \right) \times \left( \bigcup_{l = 1}^n D_l \right)$ and hence $E = \bigcup_{k = 1}^m C_k$ and $F = \bigcup_{l = 1}^n D_l$. ...

... All of this is actually obvious when you actually draw it: The $A_j \times B_j$ are some disjoint rectangles whose union is the rectangle $E \times F$.

@Smiley1000 Thanks, I got the point now.

Make sure to write up your final solution as an answer and accept it!

@Smiley1000 Actually, I think there is one last (small) problem. I need to show that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{p} \sum \limits_{l=1}^{q} \mu(C_k) \cdot \nu(D_l)$ is equal to $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{m_j} \sum \limits_{l=1}^{n_l} \mu(C_{j_k}) \cdot \nu(D_{j_l})$. This is true if $A_{j_1} \cap A_{j_2} \neq \emptyset$ and $B_{j_1} \cap B_{j_2} \neq \emptyset$ for $j_1 \neq j_2$. But we only know that $(A_{j_1} \times B_{j_1}) \cap (A_{j_2} \cap B_{j_2}) \neq \emptyset$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Obviously, $\rho(\emptyset) = \mu(\emptyset) \cdot \nu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\rho \geq 0$ since $\mu \geq 0$ and $\nu \geq 0$. Now let $A_1 \times B_1,...,A_n \times B_n \in \mathfrak{H} * \mathfrak{K}$ with $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j \in \mathfrak{H} * \mathfrak{K}$. Then $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j = E \times F$ for some $E \in \mathfrak{H}$ and $F \in \mathfrak{K}$. Using Exercise I.5.5, we know there are disjoint sets $C_1,...,C_p \in \mathfrak{H}$ and disjoint sets $D_1,...,D_q \in \mathfrak{K}$ such that each $A_j (j=1,...,n)$ can be written as a union of some $C_k$ and each $B_j (j=1,...,n)$ can be written as a union of some $D_l$, respectively. WLOG we can assume that each of the sets $C_1,...,C_p$ is a subset of some $A_j$ and each $D_1,...,D_q$ is a subset of some $B_j$, respectively.
I claim that $E \times F = \bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{p} C_k \times \bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{q} D_l$. The arguments above show that there is $j_1,j_2$ such that $C_k \times D_l \subset A_{j_1} \times A_{j_2} \subset E \times F$, and thus $\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{p} C_k \times \bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{q} D_l \subset E \times F = \bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j$.
Furthermore, $\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j = \bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} \left(\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{p_j} C_{j_k} \times \bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{q_l} D_{j_l} \right) \subset \left(\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{p} C_k \right) \times \left(\bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{q} D_l \right)$, and so $E \times F = \left(\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{p} C_k \right) \times \left(\bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{q} D_l \right)$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
\rho \left(\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j \right) & = \rho \left(\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{p} C_k \times \bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{q} D_l \right) = \mu \left(\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{p} C_k \right) \cdot \nu \left(\bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{q} D_l \right) \\
  & = \left(\sum \limits_{k=1}^{p} \mu(C_k) \right) \cdot \left(\sum \limits_{l=1}^{q} \nu(D_l) \right) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{p} \sum \limits_{l=1}^{q} \mu(C_k) \cdot \nu(D_l).
\end{align*}
Also,
\begin{align*}
\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \rho(A_j \times B_j) & = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \rho \left(\left(\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{m_j} C_{j_k} \right) \times \left(\bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{n_j} D_{j_j} \right) \right) \\
  & = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \mu\left(\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{m_j} C_{j_k} \right) \cdot \nu \left(\bigcup \limits_{l=1}^{n_j} D_{j_j} \right) \\
  & = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{m_j} \sum \limits_{l=1}^{n_l} \mu(C_{j_k}) \cdot \nu(D_{j_l}).
\end{align*}
Since the sets $A_j \times B_j$ are disjoint, no combination of $C_k$ and $D_l$ occurs multiple times in this sum and hence
$$\rho \left(\bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j \times B_j \right) = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \rho(A_j \times B_j).$$
